# PHP script failing on Updating Web Form

Tags: php

Thanks to everyone who gave me help with previous trouble. I have my scripts working so I can add & display entries. Now I was following along with this tutorial to update the entries but I am getting this error on page when I run it:
 ! ) Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/inventory/update.php on line 21
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0000  229608  {main}( )   ../update.php:0
The code looks like this:

```
 <?php
    ini_set("display_errors","on");

    $dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inventory_form';
    $username="***";
    $password="****";
    $database="inventory_form";


    try
        {
        $link=new PDO($dsn, $username,$password);
        echo 'Connected to MySQL Server';
        }
    catch (PDOException $e)
        {
        $error_message=$e->getMessage();
        echo "<h1>An error occurred: $error_message</h1>";
        }

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=$link->query($query);

    while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
        echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['FName'] .'</font></b></i></center><br /n>';
        echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['LName'] .'</font></b></i></center><br /n>';
        echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['Eqpmnt_Brwd'] .'</font></b></i></center><br /n>';
        echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['Service_Tag'] .'</font></b></i></center>';
        echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['Date_Taken'] .'</font></b></i></center>';
        echo '<b><i><font size=5>'. $row['Comments'] .'</font></b></i>';

      }

    ?>

    <form action="updated.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ud_id" value="<? echo "$id"; ?>">
    <font size=5>First Name:</font><input type="text" name="ud_first" maxlength="12" 
size="12" />
    <font size=5>Last Name:</font><input type="text" name="ud_last" maxlength="36" size="12" />
    <font size=5>Equipment Borrowed:</font><input type="text" name="ud_Equipment_Borrowed" maxlength="60" size="14" /><br />
    <font size=5>Service Tag:</font><input type="text" name="ud_Service_Tag" maxlength="6" size="6" /><br />
    <font size=5>Date Taken:</font><input type="text" name="ud_Date_Taken" /><br />
    <font size=5>Additional Comments:</font><br /> 
        <textarea name="ud_Comments" maxlength="150" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea> <br /> <br />
    <input type="Submit" value="Update">
    </form>
    ?/
```

And then I get a bunch of errors from the updated.php script:
 Notice: Undefined variable: ud_first in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 19
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0002  231664  {main}( )   ../updated.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: ud_last in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 19
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0002  231664  {main}( )   ../updated.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: ud_Equipmnt_borrowed in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 19
etc for all variables.
That script is:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inventory_form';
$username="***";
$password="****";
$database="inventory_form";

try
    {
    $link=new PDO($dsn, $username,$password);
    echo 'Record added succesfully';
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    $error_message=$e->getMessage();
    echo "<h1>An error occurred: $error_message</h1>";
    }

$query="UPDATE contacts SET FName='$ud_first', LName='$ud_last', Eqmnt_Brwd='$ud_Equipmnt_borrowed', Service_Tag='$ud_Service_Tag', Date_Taken='$ud_Date_Taken', Comments='$ud_Comments' WHERE id='$ud_id'";

echo "Record Updated";

?>
```

Any help much appreciated. I'm a little confuse on how the id field is being used to make this all work. According to tutorial I should have a filled in form ready to edit for a particular entry.Thanks in advance

Update. Here is code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");

$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inventory_form';
$username="***";
$password="*****";
$database="inventory_form";


try
    {
    $link=new PDO($dsn, $username,$password);
    echo 'Connected to MySQL Server';
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    $error_message=$e->getMessage();
    echo "<h1>An error occurred: $error_message</h1>";
    }

$id=htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);

$query="SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE id='$id'";
$result=$link->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
    echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['FName'] .'</font></b></i></center><br /n>';
    echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['LName'] .'</font></b></i></center><br /n>';
    echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['Eqpmnt_Brwd'] .'</font></b></i></center><br /n>';
    echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['Service_Tag'] .'</font></b></i></center>';
    echo '<b><i><center><font size=5>'. $row['Date_Taken'] .'</font></b></i></center>';
    echo '<b><i><font size=5>'. $row['Comments'] .'</font></b></i>';

  }

?>

<form action="updated.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ud_id" value="<? echo "$id"; ?>">
<font size=5>First Name:</font><input type="text" name="ud_first" maxlength="12" size="12" />
<font size=5>Last Name:</font><input type="text" name="ud_last" maxlength="36" size="12" />
<font size=5>Equipment Borrowed:</font><input type="text" name="ud_Equipment_Borrowed" maxlength="60" size="14" /><br />
<font size=5>Service Tag:</font><input type="text" name="ud_Service_Tag" maxlength="6" size="6" /><br />
<font size=5>Date Taken:</font><input type="text" name="ud_Date_Taken" /><br />
<font size=5>Additional Comments:</font><br /> 
    <textarea name="ud_Comments" maxlength="150" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea> <br /> <br />
<input type="Submit" value="Update">
</form>


?>
```

Comment: Are the variables in your query initialized?

Comment: Look! You are fetching data from inventory table and updating contacts table. What you doing?

Comment: You're right! Was left over from code I was looking at. Changed it to correct db but if you look below at pastebin site script still says Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/inventory/update.php on line 21 and Notice: Undefined variable: ud_id in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 26 for updated.php script that is called

Answer (score 0):

First one: You have to add something like '?id=NUMBER' at the end of the url (example: update.php?id=1') to use the ID

For that, you have to use:

```
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'])
```

Second one: You used $ud_last etc. but didn't define them in your code, you have to do it like:

```
$ud_last = $_POST['ud_last'];
```

Then it should work

Comment: Sorry but I added line: 
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'])
$id=$_POST['id'];

$query="SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE id='$id'";
$result=$link->query($query);
And I'm just getting white page. I dont even get connection message.

Comment: You've defined $id two times now, you shouldn't define $id using $_POST['id'] in this case (you have to define those ud_last etc. using that)

Comment: Did this still get white page:

Comment: Weird, it should at least be giving errors ;S Can you put the whole updated code in you post or @ jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Getting error message:! ) Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/inventory/update.php on line 21
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0004 232088 {main}( ) ../update.php:0  code is :$id=htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);

$query="SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE id='$id'";
$result=$link->query($query);

Comment: See original post. Added whole script. Running on Ubuntu 13.10 w/PHP 5.5 I believe.

Comment: According to your error I think you still didn't go to update.php?id=1 but just to update.php, that means there's no htmlspecialchar called 'id' to define

Comment: Wow you kinda lost me.Aren't I suppose to go to updated.php from script? Now that I think about it I thought I read where you cant use _GET with _POST?

Comment: I thought your script was called updated.php but you should go to whateveryouscriptiscalled.php?id=aNUMBER ;)

Comment: No.script is update.php. It then calls updated.php via action=. I posted that script in original post

Comment: Well, doesn't really matter, does it give you errors when you add ?id=1 ?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I wasnt sure where to add. When I add it to line <form action="updated.php?id=1" method="post"> get same ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/inventory/update.php on line 21

Comment: $id=htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']); means that for example: When I have a page called example.php and I add the `$id=htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);` in that page it gives an error when I browse to example.php, but when I browse to example.php?id=1 it doesn't give the error. The form should be working fine without the ?id=1

Comment: But I'm no expert(as you could tell:)Also the Updated.php is complaining that  Undefined variable: ud_id in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 26. I guess basic question is why is id(undefined index) in update.php and ud_id(undefined variable) in updated.php not being defined? I also changed some lines because example from http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/7 didnt look right 
<form action="updated.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ud_id" value="<? echo $id>"

Comment: Is there a way to upload the two files to you so you could look at them?

Comment: If you just upload your code's at http://pastebin.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ and paste the links in your question I'll look into them and change the thing that are wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate that. The link is: http://pastebin.com/Yz609XPv for the two files. If you need backround you can see the previous link I was trying to follow. But he lost me with using the id field to make this work???

Comment: It was just a little mistake, fixed it [here](http://pastebin.com/6qXnE2ZV), you an view the difference [here](http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=6qXnE2ZV)

Comment: Hi. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I pasted in code direct from pastebin and got same exact error message:Undefined index: id in /var/www/inventory/update.php on line 21. And I dont see any difference in the two scripts?

Comment: You should still browse to update.php?id=NUMBER ;) And the error was in the query, I changed that

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately now entry appears first and fields are blank like so: 
Mary

Smith

laptop

544344
2014-06-07
First Name: Last Name: Equipment Borrowed:
Service Tag:
Date Taken:
Additional Comments:
 And when I fill in fields nothing is updated. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Looking at the original example I should be doing the equivalent of:while ($i < $num) {
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"first");
$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"last");
$phone=mysql_result($result,$i,"phone");
$Eqpmnt_Brwd=mysql_result($result,$i,"Eqmnt_Brwd");
$Sevice_Tag=mysql_result($result,$i,"Service_tag");
etc for all keys. Could you tell me what the correct syntax would be   because I dont believe from before that my_sql_result can be used with _Post,correct? And also what would take the place of the i and $result variable?

Comment: Then he has for last segment of update:First Name: <input type="text" name="ud_first" value="<? echo $ud_first; ?>"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="ud_last" value="<? echo $ud_last; ?>"><br> etc for each variablel. Is that the correct syntax? Sorry for so much to ask. The jist of what should happen is the update page should appear with the fields already filled in ready to modify then make changes and submit where updated.php will make the changes to the table.

Comment: The result is something you already entered `$result=$link->query($query);` Can you look into his code and search for `$i = ...`?

Comment: Long story short I modified the two scripts per advice on a another question I posted. The update scripts I posted at http://pastebin.com/Yz609XPv. Unfortunately still get an error when the called script updated.php runs: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 37. At this point I don't blame you if you want to walk away seeing as this is much more complicated that originally thought. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm also noticing when I change the line in update.php to:<form action="updated.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="ud_id" value="<? echo $id>"?> I dont get the id number in the field I get "<? echo $ id>". So I'm not passing the integer to updated.php if that helps.