# Updating Table w/PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script that receives the updated data from script called update.php and updates the database entry. The code for updated.php:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inventory_form';
$username="****";
$password="*****";
$database="inventory_form";

$FName_val=$_POST['ud_first'];
$LName_val=$_POST['ud_last'];
$Eqpmnt_Brwd_val=$_POST['ud_Equipment_Borrowed'];
$Service_Tag_val=$_POST['ud_Service_Tag'];
$Date_Taken_val=$_POST['ud_Date_Taken'];
$Comments_val=$_POST['ud_Comments'];
$id_val=$_POST['ud_id'];
try
    {
    $link=new PDO($dsn, $username,$password);
    echo 'Connected To MySQL OK';
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    $error_message=$e->getMessage();
    echo "<h1>An error occurred: $error_message</h1>";
    }

$query = "UPDATE Inventory SET FName='$FName_val', LName='$LName_val', Eqmnt_Brwd='$Eqpmnt_Brwd_val', Service_Tag='$Service_Tag_val', Date_Taken='$Date_Taken_val', Comments='$Comments_val' WHERE id_val='$id_val'";
$result=$link->query($query);
echo "Record Updated";
echo $LName_val;
?>
```

I receive no errors and  see the LName_val print out but the database is not being updated. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Uses PDO... Injects values into query anyway >_>

Comment: Use a prepared query in case any of the parameters contain quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry new to all this. Could you be more specific. I dont have to list the db id field in the Update/Set command,correct?

Comment: Add `$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, since you're not checking for errors.

Comment: Plus, in your [**other question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24411496/) you're using `WHERE id='$id'` and in this one it's `WHERE id_val='$id_val'`. I also noticed your use of short open tags syntax `value="<? echo "$id"; ?>"`. If those are not "ON", you'll need to use `value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>"`

Comment: Yeah I was advised to change to id_val=id_val.I changed the value= tp ?php but still get Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 37

Comment: Check your column names and make sure you don't have one that contains a typo. Column names are case-sensitive, meaning that `Username` is not the same as `username`, or that your column(s) have a hyphen or a space instead of what you're using now, being underscores to act as word seperators. Even if "one" if off, your entire query will fail. Make absolutely certain. Plus, if you can provide DB schema, we can tell right away, or at least know what we're dealing with.

Comment: Plus, did you add what I posted above about `$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`?

Comment: I also noticed another thing, you're not "executing" your query (why didn't I spot that earlier?). You need to do something like `$result=$link->execute($query);` - Here's an example page for you to see http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html and see this Q&A on SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/18323065/

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared query:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("UPDATE Inventory 
                        SET FName = :FName, LName = :LName, Eqmnt_Brwd = :Eqmnt_Brwd, 
                        Service_Tag = :Service_Tag, Date_Taken = :Date_Taken, Comments = :Comments
                        WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':FName' => $FName_val,
    ':LName' => $LName_val,
    ':Eqmnt_Brwd' => $Eqmnt_Brwd_val,
    ':Service_Tag' => $Service_Tag_val,
    ':Date_Taken' => $Date_Taken_val,
    ':Comments' => $Comments_val,
    ':id' => $id_val));
```

This will avoid problems if any of the values contain quotes.

Also, you need to change

```
WHERE id_val =
```

to:

```
WHERE id =
```

Comment: Thanks b ut still getting error:Connected To MySQL OK
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /var/www/inventory/updated.php on line 37

Comment: Make sure all the keys in the array match the placeholders in the query. It's case sensitive, so make sure that matches.

Comment: OP's got quite a few similarly related questions. Column names seem to have changed over a course of time; hard to pinpoint exactly where OP's errors are being made.

Comment: Yes they all match. Here is link to first php script that calls this one: http://pastebin.com/2kaAJSb9. Here id does not cause a problem?

Comment: I don't care about that script. It's complaining about an error in THIS script. I think you didn't write the prepared statement correctly.

Comment: Your pastebin file's using `WHERE id=` you say this works, yet your posted code's using `WHERE id_val=` (which one is it?). Did you not read the comments I placed under your original question? @Alan

Comment: @Fred-ii- They're two different scripts, why should variable names be the same? All that matters is that the variable you use is the same one that you assign in that same script.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This script does `$id_val = $_POST['ud_id']`, that script does `$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'])`.

Comment: I wasn't talking about variable names, I was talking about column names.

Comment: But that wouldn't cause the `Invalid parameter number` error that he said he got.

Comment: Which just leaves a lot of room for error and confusion. Without seeing OP's DB schema, we can't be 100% certain as to where the error lies.

Comment: *Hm*... I do remember seeing a question not so long ago where a bound `id` was the fault. Maybe OP's got an AI on the `id` column?

Comment: Here's schema: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
Field Type Null Key Default Extra 
FName varchar(12) NO  NULL 
LName varchar(15) NO  NULL 
Eqpmnt_Brwd varchar(25) NO  NULL 
Service_Tag text NO  NULL 
Date_Taken date NO  NULL 
Comments varchar(150) NO  NULL 
id int(11) NO PRI NULL auto_increment

Comment: Please don't waste our time trying to put formatted data in comments, they're totally unreadable. And why do I care if those features are available?

Comment: I'm sorry but I thought Fred ii was looking for the DB schema that's all. I will go back and try to sort this out on my own.

Comment: He did ask to see that. Add it to the question, not a comment.